# How to add multiple UILabels programmatically in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Hello in Xcode I am trying to add two labels to my image programmatically but when I add the second one it will overwrite my first one. Here is my code:

```
    //first label
    UILabel* caption = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
                        CGRectMake(-25, 0, 320, 50)
                        ];
    caption.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    caption.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    caption.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    caption.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    caption.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  @%@",[data objectForKey:@"username"]];
    [self addSubview: caption];

    //second label
    UILabel* bottomBox = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
                        CGRectMake(-25, -200, 320, 50)
                        ];
    caption.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    caption.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    caption.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    caption.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    caption.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  Testing"];
    [self addSubview: bottomBox];
```

I've tried changing the "0 to -200 to modify the Y coordinates so that the second label will shift down but it just overwrites the first one for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: Why are you using negative coordinates? IF you want the 2nd below the 1st, use 200, not -200.

Comment: You're setting the attributes for the caption label in both cases. First you set the text to @"username" and then @"testing". You're not actually setting any properties on the bottomBox label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the code for your 2nd label is referencing the 1st variable `caption` instead of `bottomBox`. You want:

```
//second label
UILabel* bottomBox = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 320, 50)];
bottomBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
bottomBox.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
bottomBox.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
bottomBox.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
bottomBox.text = @"Testing";
[self addSubview: bottomBox];
```